# Chrome 27 window.opener cross-domain message

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, window.opener

This is on Chrome 27, after viewing many of the other answers here.
In a parent html page, when the user clicks a button, this function gets executed:

```
var newWindow = window.open("hello.html");
```

Now, the hello.html page has this code (along with a basic html structure):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log($("#search-button", window.opener));
    });
</script>
```

The point is to be able to "send" some data from hello.html to the parent page.
Here's Chrome's message:

> Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: First of all, are the new window really needed? Many things can be solved by simple in-page dialogs or modals. See jQuery UI or Twitter bootstrap for example.